# Onde colocar arquivos PDF numa aplicação desenvolvida no Android Studio

Tags: android

Colegas. Tenho uma dúvida de programação para Android, vejam se vocês podem me ajudar. Estou desenvolvendo um APP que precisa abrir alguns arquivos PDF que deve vir junto com a aplicação.

A ideia é chamar uma Intent para abrir estes arquivos PDF pelo próprio leitor PDF nativo do Android. Em que pasta (dentro do diretório res) coloco estes arquivos? Como faço para a intenção abrir o PdF com o caminho deste arquivo?

Algum sugestão ou ideia de como posso fazer isto?

Comment: Serei curto: coloque os pdfs na pasta `assets`.

Comment: Leia mais sobre essa pasta nesta pergunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302603/where-do-i-place-the-assets-folder-in-android-studio

Comment: Quando você resolver o seu problema, poste a solução como resposta! abraços.